# PIL Drawing a semi-transparent square overlay on image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw 
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W4qijIdAPZA/maxresdefault.jpg"
file = BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())
img = Image.open(file)
img = img.convert("RGBA")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, "RGBA")
draw.rectangle(((0, 00), (img.size[0], img.size[1])), fill=(0,0,0,127))
img.save('dark-cat.jpg')
```

This is giving me a giant black square. I want it to be a semi transparent black square with a cat. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sorry, the comment I made about it being a bug was incorrect, so...

You can do it by creating a temporary image and using [`Image.alpha_composite()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.alpha_composite) as shown in the code below. Note that it supports semi-transparent squares other than black.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

TINT_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)  # Black
TRANSPARENCY = .25  # Degree of transparency, 0-100%
OPACITY = int(255 * TRANSPARENCY)

url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W4qijIdAPZA/maxresdefault.jpg"
with BytesIO(urlopen(url).read()) as file:
    img = Image.open(file)
    img = img.convert("RGBA")

# Determine extent of the largest possible square centered on the image.
# and the image's shorter dimension.
if img.size[0] > img.size[1]:
    shorter = img.size[1]
    llx, lly = (img.size[0]-img.size[1]) // 2 , 0
else:
    shorter = img.size[0]
    llx, lly = 0, (img.size[1]-img.size[0]) // 2

# Calculate upper point + 1 because second point needs to be just outside the
# drawn rectangle when drawing rectangles.
urx, ury = llx+shorter+1, lly+shorter+1

# Make a blank image the same size as the image for the rectangle, initialized
# to a fully transparent (0% opaque) version of the tint color, then draw a
# semi-transparent version of the square on it.
overlay = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, TINT_COLOR+(0,))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(overlay)  # Create a context for drawing things on it.
draw.rectangle(((llx, lly), (urx, ury)), fill=TINT_COLOR+(OPACITY,))

# Alpha composite these two images together to obtain the desired result.
img = Image.alpha_composite(img, overlay)
img = img.convert("RGB") # Remove alpha for saving in jpg format.
img.save('dark-cat.jpg')
img.show()
```

Here's the result of applying it to your test image:

[image: picture of a cat with blacken square rectangle superimposed on it]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just created a new issue : https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2496

Comment: @ChaseRoberts it's not a bug, it's a misunderstanding of what `Draw` is supposed to do. It doesn't do blending, it replaces one set of pixels with a new set. The [example in the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text) shows that this is a two-step process, drawing with opacity on a blank canvas then compositing the result. As shown in the second part of this answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Indeed, so my workaround is _the_ way to do it (generally speaking).

Comment: @MarkRansom I read the whole `ImageDraw` docs and found nothing about the way it is intended to do...

Comment: @MinhNghĩa: Admittedly, the docs _are_ pretty terse on the subject. Perhaps the Wikipedia article on [alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) would help your understand of what it does.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa then it's a good thing we have StackOverflow!  It's possible that the authors of ImageDraw thought it was so self-evident that there was no need to explain it.

Comment: How is the statement `OPACITY = 255 * TRANSPARENCY` supposed to make any sense, these are two diametrically opposed concepts...

Answer (score 22):

Given that I keep coming back to this issue whenever I want to draw a transparent rectangle with PIL, I decided to give an update.

Your code is pretty much working for me if I just change one thing: Save the image in the PNG format instead of JPEG.

So when I'm running

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W4qijIdAPZA/maxresdefault.jpg"
file = BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())
img = Image.open(file)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, "RGBA")
draw.rectangle(((280, 10), (1010, 706)), fill=(200, 100, 0, 127))
draw.rectangle(((280, 10), (1010, 706)), outline=(0, 0, 0, 127), width=3)
img.save('orange-cat.png')
```

I get this wonderful image:

[image: cat with semi-transparent orange bounding box]

Comment: fill=int, complains about tuple https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html

Comment: I'm running Pillow 8.2.0 and I'm not seeing any complaints when running the code above.

Comment: Splendid! Thank you sir. (Although it should be noted dogs are infinitely better than cats)

Comment: This (somewhat surprisingly) works when the original image lacks an alpha channel - in other cases, the alpha_composite solution described above is your best bet.

Comment: @Quppa: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620169/355230) also works when the original image lacks an alpha channel (as the `maxresdefault.jpg` image used does). It's also more generic in the sense that the size of the square area tinted is determined dynamically based on the source image rather than being hardcoded in.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to dim the entire image, there's a simpler way:

```
img = Image.eval(img, lambda x: x/2)
```