# How do I add a transparent overlay to an image using pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to add an transparent overlay on an jpeg image. In the example below, the desired result would be a red image with a pieslice where the it is light red.

My input is an jpeg Image. Since jpeg doesn't have an alpha channel, I though I could convert it to an 'RGBA' image and paste the overlay on it:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# img = Image.open('input.jpg').convert('RGBA')
img = Image.new('RGBA', (400,400), (255,0,0))

img2 = Image.new('RGBA', (400,400))
draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
draw2.pieslice([0,0,400,400], 90, 180, fill='white')
img.putalpha(128)

img.save('img.png')
img2.save('img2.png')

img.paste(img2)
img.save('img1+2.png')
```

However, this doesn't have the desired effect, and windows Photos cannot even open it correctly.

I saw the `blend` and `alpha_composite` functions but it doesn't have the desired effect for me. I don't want to lower the alpha values of the background outside of the overlay.

Comment: Possible dup of  [PIL Drawing a semi-transparent square overlay on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618910/pil-drawing-a-semi-transparent-square-overlay-on-image)?