# How to lower transparency to line in Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How to lower opacity to line? I would like to lower opacity to one of line in example bellow.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.line((100, 30, 0, 30), (0, 0, 0), 20)
draw.line((100, 70, 0, 70), (0, 0, 0), 20)
img.show()
```

I have seen in one example they created opacity like this...

```
TRANSPARENCY = .25  # Degree of transparency, 0-100%
OPACITY = int(255 * TRANSPARENCY)
```

But don't know how to apply to one of lines. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I made some changes (based on answer of @Pedro Maia), it still doesn't work, just changes a color, it doesn't lower opacity to see background color.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGBA', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
TRANSPARENCY = .25  # Degree of transparency, 0-100%
draw.line((200, 0, 200, 600),(255, 0, 0), 60)
draw.line((500, 100, 0, 100), (0, 0, 0, int(255 * TRANSPARENCY)), 60)
draw.line((500, 400, 0, 400),(0, 0, 0), 60)
img
```

And I have to convert it to RGB to export it as 'jpg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like this, which is similar to how the [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618910/pil-drawing-a-semi-transparent-square-overlay-on-image) works, to do what (I think) you want to. I changed the code you added to your question in the **EDIT** slightly so it better demonstrates that lines of different amounts of transparency can be drawn.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Calculate alpha given a 0-100% opacity value.
opacity = lambda transparency: (int(255 * (transparency/100.)),)  # Returns a monuple.

def draw_transp_line(image, xy, color, width=1, joint=None):
    """ Draw line with transparent color on the specified image. """
    if len(color) < 4:  # Missing alpha?
        color += opacity(100)  # Opaque since alpha wasn't specified.

    # Make an overlay image the same size as the specified image, initialized to
    # a fully transparent (0% opaque) version of the line color, then draw a
    # semi-transparent line on it.
    overlay = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, color[:3]+opacity(0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(overlay)  # Create a context for drawing things on it.
    draw.line(xy, color, width, joint)
    # Alpha composite the overlay image onto the original.
    image.alpha_composite(overlay)


# Create opaque white RGBA background image.
img = Image.new('RGBA', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255)+opacity(100))

draw_transp_line(img, ((200, 0), (200, 600)), RED+opacity(100), 60)
draw_transp_line(img, ((500, 100), (0, 100)), BLACK+opacity(25), 60)
draw_transp_line(img, ((150, 50), (600, 400)), BLACK+opacity(50), 60)

img = img.convert("RGB") # Remove alpha for saving in jpg format.
img.save('transparent_lines.jpg')
img.show()
```

JPG image created:

[image: resulting JPG image]

Answer (score 0):

With draw.line you can pass as argument `RGB` or `RGBA` just pass the value of the transparency:

```
draw.line((100, 30, 0, 30), (0, 0, 0, int(255 * TRANSPARENCY)), 20)
```

Also when creating the image set it as `RGBA`:

```
img = Image.new('RGBA', (100, 100), (255, 255, 255))
```

Comment: Nothing changes, can you provide an image?

Comment: You also have to set image mode to `RGBA`

Comment: It just changes color, it doesn't make that you can see from one color the background color. Please see updated question.